# Use AWS CLI to delete certain managed policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am able to fetch one policy from all AWS accounts using below command.

```
aws --profile ${profile} iam list-policies --query 'Policies[?starts_with(PolicyName,`Policy-dynamo-db`)]'
```

Now I am trying to delete the policy using AWS-CLI from all my aws accounts using policy name. Is it possible to delete the policy using policy name? OR do I need to fetch the policy ARN for all the AWS accounts to delete. Any help with the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :

Detach first policy from role.

```
aws iam delete-role-policy --role-name Test-Role --policy-name ExamplePolicy
```

And only way to delete policy is using ARN

```
aws iam delete-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/MySamplePolicy
```

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/delete-role-policy.html

**Note** : if your AWS IAM user doesn't have access to policy then you will not able list or delete those policy.

Comment: if this help answer you can accept answer you enough reputation to accept answer.@hashimvayalar

Comment: Works fine. I have to detach the policy first.